# confused about (よ)うとした

Tags: grammar

i have saw two different meaning in different context.

1.うとした means wanted to do something,but didn’t actually perform the action

> ドアを開けようとしたが、鍵がかかっていました。

2.うとした means wanted to do something,and actually performed it

> トットちゃんは、顔をななめにしたまま、表札を読みあげた。そして、ママに、 「トモエって、なあに？」 　と聞こうとしたときだった。

I don’t know what caused the differences ,how I can tell whether the subject already take the action or not?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: the action is taken in neither quotes. The door is still closed and the question remains unasked (but confusingly writers are able to read characters' mind!)

I hope this helps